# How to remove the user profile folder from navigation pane in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, aero

How do I remove the user profile folder from navigation pane in Windows Explorer on Windows 10?

[image]

Seems like none of the currently recommended solutions work no more, including editing the following Registry keys:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}` and
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432node\CLSID\{59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee}`

setting the `DWORD` key `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` to `0`.

This folder is automaticaly expanded when Windows Explorer is started; for me it contains over 30 mostly useless items - completely takes over the navigation pane.

Comment: The thing you need to get rid of is in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\], I won't give you the exact GUID, you have to find it yourself, be warned if you do you might be unable to rename folders, the solution is to restore the FolderDescriptions registry key with a .reg file, you will need TrustedInstaller rights to do that.